# Making a line graph with certain X + Y values expressed differently with lines of 33 user IDs in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar, linegraph

I'm trying to put ActivityDate on the X Axis, and Calories on the Y Axis, relating to how 33 different users ranged in their calorie burnings daily. I'm new to ggplot and visualizations as you can tell, so I'd appreciate the most basic solution that I can understand. Thank you so much.

I really tried several iterations of this code, and each one of them weren't quite right in how the visualization turned out. Here are a couple of my thoughts:

##first and foremost:
`install.packages("tidyverse") install.packages("here") library(tidyverse) library(here)`

### Attempt 1 Bar Graph

`ggplot(data=trimmed_dactivity) + geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=Id, color=ActivityDate))`

[Attempt 1 Bar Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk2aa.png)
##Not probably the best for stakeholders, but if I could maybe have the bars a little closer together that might help, so I tried to identify the unique IDs. Perhaps the reason why they are so small is that they appear in long number format, and are not sequential, so it could be adding the extra space and making the bars so small because of the spaces of empty sequential numbers.

### Attempt 2 Bar Graph

`UId <- unique("Id") ggplot(data=trimmed_dactivity) + geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=UId, color=ActivityDate))`

[Attempt 2 Bar Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIDHB.png)
##*Facepalm*, definitely not what I was looking for at all, but that was my effort to solve the above problem.

### Attempt 3 Bar Graph

`ggplot(data=trimmed_dactivity) + geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=ActivityDate, fill=Id)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45))`

[Attempt 3 Bar Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by1MJ.png)
##The fill function does not work, and on the y-axis if you will, I don't know what "count" is referring to in this case, so could be useful except for those two issues.

##Finally, I switch to a line graph

### Attempt 4 Line Graph

`ggplot(data=trimmed_dactivity) +  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=ActivityDate, y=Calories)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45))`

[Attempt 4 Line Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgjUr.png)
##Now what I get is separate lines going up and down, and what I want is 33 separate lines representing unique Id numbers to travel along the x axis for time, and rise in the y axis for calories. Of course I'm not sure how to do that...

Any help with what I'm missing on this journey here?

Comment: Hi Eve, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will help us help you if you can share your data in a copy-pasteable format. To do so, run `dput(trimmed_dactivity)` in R, then [edit] your post to add the result. Also have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I want is 33 separate lines representing unique Id numbers…

It sounds like you want a spaghetti plot. To make one, map `Id` to `color` (or to `group` if you don’t want each id to be colored differently).

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(fakedata, aes(ActivityDate, Calories)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(Id)), show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

*Example data:*

```
set.seed(13)

fakedata <- expand.grid(
  Id = 1:33,
  ActivityDate = seq(as.Date("2016-04-13"), length.out = 10, by = "day")
)

fakedata$Calories <- round(rnorm(330, 2500, 500))
```